# Cronjob does not get executed

Tags: php, cron

I have created two cron job:

```
crontab -e

0 0,6,12,18 * * * php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/thenwat/preInvite_karim/frrole/topurl.php
* * * * * php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/thenwat/invite/hash.php
~
```

but none of these get executed, anything wrong?

First there was only firstone. Later I added 2nd but both show no action.

**UPDATE**

Files in `/var/log` dir. Which one is of my concern?

```
audit              btmp-20140101   cron-20140112        mail              messages-20131229  secure-20140105   spooler-20140119
boot.log           cloud-init.log  cron-20140119        maillog           messages-20140105  secure-20140112   tallylog
boot.log-20131229  conman          dmesg                maillog-20131229  messages-20140112  secure-20140119   wtmp
boot.log-20140105  conman.old      dmesg.old            maillog-20140105  messages-20140119  spooler           yum.log
boot.log-20140112  cron            dracut.log           maillog-20140112  ntpstats           spooler-20131229  yum.log-20120101
boot.log-20140119  cron-20131229   dracut.log-20120101  maillog-20140119  secure             spooler-20140105  yum.log-20131004
btmp               cron-20140105   lastlog              messages          secure-20131229    spooler-20140112  yum.log-20140101
```

Comment: Any error trace in /var/log ?

Comment: @Alfabravo: can you please see update

Comment: Try using full php path e.g. /usr/bin/php

Comment: @DhruvPathak: did you mean : `* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/thenwat/invite/hash.php` ?? does 2nd cron job is correctly written to execute every minute?

Comment: I used this but still no luck

Comment: I would test my luck searching in cron and dmesg. Try grepping: grep CRON /var/log/<filename>

Comment: Can you run the command on it's own from the command line? $ php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/thenwat/preInvite_karim/frrole/topurl.php

Comment: @Grant: thanks for this. it does not run it. it gives error : `-bash: php: command not found
`

Comment: @Alfabravo: no, it says : `grep CRON /var/log/hash.php
grep: /var/log/hash.php: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Sorry, with <filename> meant "dmesg" or "cron". That's to search the string "CRON" in those files

Answer (score 1):

Try and run the command on it's own on the command line:

```
$ php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/thenwat/preInvite_karim/frrole/topurl.php
```

This will verify if the command is working as it should, if not debug the command until it works and then add it to Cron.

This should sort it out for you.

Looks like you need the correct path to PHP: run this: /usr/bin/php -v

If that doesn't work try this: /usr/local/bin/php -v